# What is the time origin of the `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` powershell command

Tags: powershell, networkstatsmanager

The powershell command `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` outputs the total bytes sent and received.

```
Name                             ReceivedBytes ReceivedUnicastPackets       SentBytes SentUnicastPackets
----                             ------------- ----------------------       --------- ------------------
Wi-Fi                              18507109591               12276490       799251283           11158174
```

But I don't see anywhere the information about when these statistics begin ? (Is this from last computer start, or anything else ??)

Comment: Why not test it?

Comment: I wanted to have a reference documentation about it. After some tests it appears that the time origin is the start of the network interface.

Comment: Which I assumed you already knew that. Only makes sense. Wish there was a property for that though. Maybe event logs?

Answer (score 1):

I did the test with my wifi network adapter and when it disconnects the statistic restarts.

Before you disconnect it:

[image]

Disconnect and reconnect it:

[image]